# AngularJS Watch input validity directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i like to watch the validity of an input element inside a directive. My controller is always `undefined`. How can i watch properties like `$valid`, `$invalid` on a input element ?

```
app.directive("myElement", function()
{
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: "./Templates/tooltip.html",
        scope: {
        },
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                   scope.$watch(function(){return controller.$invalid;},function(newVal,oldVal){
                   });
                }
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: `controller.$invalid` only works if the controller is a **FormController** http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `controller` argument of the (pre-, post-, -) link function to work you have to require one or more controllers:

```
return {
    require: "ngModel",
    ...
};
```

Or more:

```
return {
    require: ["ngModel", "foo", "bar"],
    ...
};
```

This will not solve your problem though; You need to define a controller in the directive and make sure that the root element of the template is a *named form*. So you can do:

Template:

```
<form name="theForm">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="foo.name" />
</form>
```

Directive:

```
return {
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.watch("theForm.myInput.$valid", function(isValid) {
            ...
        });
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: i like to avoid to use a form. need a solution without it.

Comment: Try adding the `{ require: "ngModel" }` part of the answer to your code, but make sure the template *is* the `<input>`, or it does not work. Keep the same code in the link function.

Comment: how can i make sure the template is <input>... just leave templateUrl away ?

Comment: If there is *no* `template`/`templateUrl`, then make sure you will be using your directive only on elements with `ng-model`. If not, Angular will throw an error (required controller not found), so it is safe.